# How to draw network diagram from data frame columns in R?

Tags: r, datetime, networkd3

I have a data frame of customers. I want to draw a customer stages as network diagram. Sample data is like below.

```
cust_id     checkin time           stage2                     stage3              checkout time
12345   2019-01-01 07:02:50     2019-01-01 07:23:25        2019-01-01 07:23:22  2019-01-01 08:37:43
56789   2019-01-01 07:25:21     2019-01-01 07:35:29        2019-01-01 07:35:27  2019-01-01 09:36:06
43256   2019-01-01 07:27:22     2019-01-01 07:42:49        NA                   2019-01-01 09:34:55
34567   2019-01-01 07:22:15     2019-01-01 08:25:35        2019-01-01 07:26:02  2019-01-01 09:00:40
89765   2019-01-01 08:29:35     2019-01-01 08:30:58        NA                   2019-01-01 09:02:48
23456   2019-01-01 08:54:12     2019-01-01 09:18:46        2019-01-01 09:08:34  2019-01-01 09:46:38
```

The raw data is look like above. There is no rule for customer i.e, Some of the customers checkout after stage2 and some of the customers has to go stage 3 and  checkout after stage 3 .

Basically , I want to draw network map of the cusomers stages like below:

```
checkin > stage2 > stage3 > checkout
             |
            checkout
```

How to do that in R?
Tried like below with networkD3 package:

```
library(igraph)
library(networkD3)
p <- simpleNetwork(df, height="100px", width="100px",        
                   Source = 1,                 # column number of source
                   Target = 5,                 # column number of target
                   linkDistance = 10,          # distance between node. Increase this value to have more space between nodes
                   charge = -900,                # numeric value indicating either the strength of the node repulsion (negative value) or attraction (positive value)
                   fontSize = 14,               # size of the node names
                   fontFamily = "serif",       # font og node names
                   linkColour = "#666",        # colour of edges, MUST be a common colour for the whole graph
                   nodeColour = "#69b3a2",     # colour of nodes, MUST be a common colour for the whole graph
                   opacity = 0.9,              # opacity of nodes. 0=transparent. 1=no transparency
                   zoom = T                    # Can you zoom on the figure?
)

p
```

Please, help me to find the way to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's one solution using `networkD3`...

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(networkD3)

data <- 
  tribble(
  ~cust_id, ~checkin.time,         ~stage2,               ~stage3,               ~checkout.time,
  12345,    "2019-01-01 07:02:50", "2019-01-01 07:23:25", "2019-01-01 07:23:22", "2019-01-01 08:37:43",
  56789,    "2019-01-01 07:25:21", "2019-01-01 07:35:29", "2019-01-01 07:35:27", "2019-01-01 09:36:06",
  43256,    "2019-01-01 07:27:22", "2019-01-01 07:42:49", NA,                    "2019-01-01 09:34:55",
  34567,    "2019-01-01 07:22:15", "2019-01-01 08:25:35", "2019-01-01 07:26:02", "2019-01-01 09:00:40",
  89765,    "2019-01-01 08:29:35", "2019-01-01 08:30:58", NA,                    "2019-01-01 09:02:48",
  23456,    "2019-01-01 08:54:12", "2019-01-01 09:18:46", "2019-01-01 09:08:34", "2019-01-01 09:46:38"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(across(!cust_id, ~ymd_hms(.x, tz = "UTC")))

data %>% 
  select(-cust_id) %>% 
  mutate(across(.fns = ~if_else(is.na(.x), NA_character_, cur_column()))) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(origin = .[[1]]) %>%
  gather("column", "source", -row, -origin) %>%
  mutate(column = match(column, names(data))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(source)) %>% 
  arrange(row, column) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(target = lead(source)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!is.na(source) & !is.na(target)) %>%
  mutate(target = if_else(target == "checkout.time", paste0(target, " from ", source), target)) %>% 
  select(source, target, origin) %>%
  group_by(source, target, origin) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  simpleNetwork()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for  taking some time  on this and when I used that code I am getting error ```Error in across(!cust_id, ~ymd_hms(.x, tz = "UTC")) : 
  could not find function "across"  ``` . I have imported the dplyr and tidyr packages also.

Comment: `across` is only in the most recent version of `dplyr`, so you will have to upgrade to v1.0+, or convert those lines to the former syntax.

Comment: @ CJ Yetman, Can we order the nodes and include directed arrows.I saw the simpleNetwork function arguments.It did not include directed true or any other argument.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the `DiagrammeR` package useful.  Converting your sample data to the formats used by Diagrammer would be awkward, so I've done it manually.

```
library(DiagrammeR)

# Manually represent your data as nodes and edges
nodes <- create_node_df(n=5, label=c("Check in", "Stage 1", "Stage 2", "Stage 3", "Check out"))
edges <- create_edge_df(from = c(1, 2, 3), to = c(2, 3, 4))
lastStage <- c(4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3)

# Create the base graph
graph <- create_graph(nodes_df=nodes, edges_df=edges) 

# Produce the customer graphs
networks <- lapply(lastStage, function(x) graph %>% add_edge(from=x, to=5) %>% render_graph())
networks[[2]]
```

Giving, as an example,

[image: DiagrammeR output]

You have considerable control over the appearance of the graph.  The DiagrammeR home page is [here](https://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/docs.html).

Comment: Why you have taken last stage as a vector? How to define that vector?

Comment: I'm assuming you want, for each customer,  an edge from the latest stage that doesn't have an `NA` value.  Values in `lastStage` are the indexes of the corresponding node in `nodes`.  So, "Check in"  has index 1, "Stage 1" has index 2, etc.  "Check out" has index 5.

Comment: But It is difficult to create manually to the whole data frame. I have 66k + records with stages columns.

Comment: You don't need to create it manually.  You can create the nodes and edges from the data you already have.  I didn't do it because it would be messy and time consuming because (a) your data isn't [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) (because stage number appears in the column names rather than as values in the data frame) and (b) you didn't post your input data in a convenient form.  Put yourself in my shoes and try to create a data.frame using only the information in your question.  `dput(df)` would have made life simpler.